# Qt QPixmap is not clear when Windows 11 scaling is more than 100%

Tags: c++, qt, qt6, windows-11

I load `QPixmap` objects from a `png` files embedded in a `qrc` file and scale them to 16x16. I use those pixmaps to draw on `QTableView` cells or in `QtItem::DecorationRole` from various models. The overall look was fine on windows 10 but when I tried on windows 11 the images displayed were blured and not clear and it turned out the windows scaling is the cause. I set the scaling factor in `Display Settings` to 125% because it was recommended by windows and a factor of 100% looked too small compared to windows 10. When the scale factor is increased `Qt` automatically detects this and scale all draw objects including texts and images, but texts are still clear unlink displayed images which become unclear. I think it is because the pixmap was resized to 16x16 and when it is scaled for larger than 100% the quality of the image drops like when zooming a small image, but how can I make `QPixmap` work across different scaling factors? Should I keep the original size and resize in demands when panting?
I currently use Qt 6.4.1 downloaded with qt online installer.
Previously I used Qt 5.12 built from sources on Windows 10 but when the application runs on windows 11 it doesn't respect the scaling factor of windows

Comment: This may be a very complicated task. But to give you some hints, try using `QIcon` instead of `QPixmap`. `QIcon` can contain glyphs in multiple resolutions and the best one is used automatically. Also try setting `setDevicePixelRatio()` for your `QPixmap`s and `QIcon`s. But before you start, read thoroughly https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/highdpi.html and make sure you understand how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify, you can start doing the following:

1. Get the current *device pixel ratio* (DPR) using [`QScreen::devicePixelRatio`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qscreen.html#devicePixelRatio-prop).

   If the architecture allows you to have multiple device pixel ratio (Windows 10+ and macOS do), you may want to check the screen where your pixmap will be displayed using [`QGuiApplication::screenAt`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qguiapplication.html#screenAt) (Qt 6), or [`QDesktopWidget::screenNumber`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopwidget.html#screenNumber) (Qt 5).
2. Set the pixmap's DPR to the one got above.
3. Scale your bitmap accordingly: *actual_size = desired_size * DPR*. So, if your DPR is 1.25 (125%) and you want the pixmap to be 100x100, then scale it to 125x125.

You can store all these pixmaps in a single `QIcon` for easier handing (as commented [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74618747/qt-qpixmap-is-not-clear-when-windows-11-scaling-is-more-than-100#comment131722764_74618747)).

Take into consideration that in systems with multiple DPR, you may need to keep track of screen changes and update the pixmap. Here some ideas:

- Listen at [`QWindow::screenChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwindow.html#screenChanged) to detect a change in the window. If not a window, you can check `QWidget::moveEvent`.
- Listen at [`QGuiApplication::screenRemoved`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#screenRemoved) to detect when the user has removed a screen and check if your widget was there (in this case it will be moved to the primary screen).

In addition, remember to [configure your application to support HiDPI](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/highdpi.html):

- Set `Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling` application attribute. This is required only in Qt 5; Qt 6 enables it by default.
- Check the [HiDPI rounding policy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#setHighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy) (default value varies between Qt 5 and Qt 6).

Comment: The steps from 1 to 3 were enough in my case until now.